# how to make sure javascript will run on major browser

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have the following JavaScript code which validates a login form, and submits if it is valid. the code works on chrome and IE.
But on Firefox it doesn't show error feedback on `passwordinfo` and `usernameinfo` (`document.getElementById("passwordinfo").innerText = "please enter password";`)
Please help me find the problem as I am going to add ajax, and it is scaring me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
    <title>welcome</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function isvalidmail(mail) {
        var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        return filter.test(mail);
    }

    function checklogin() {
        var email = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        if(email.length < 1 || email.length > 30||(!isvalidmail(email)))
            document.getElementById("usernameinfo").innerText = "please enter valid email";
        else {
            document.getElementById("usernameinfo").innerText = "";
            if(password.length === 0) 
                document.getElementById("passwordinfo").innerText = "please enter password";
            else {
                document.getElementById("passwordinfo").innerText = "";
                document.forms["login"].submit();
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="checkCookies()">
        <script>
            function checkCookies(){
                if (!navigator.cookieEnabled==true){
                    document.write("You need to enable cookies to make the site work properly.<br>Please          enable cookies and <a href='index.php'>Reload</a>");
                }
            }
        </script>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="headerpart">
                <?php include "module_header.php" ?>
            </div>
            <div id="bodypart">
                <div id="nav">      
                    <?php 
                    include 'navigation_bar.php';
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div id="mainop">
                    <span id="sessionexp"><?php if(isset($_GET["redirect"]))if($_GET["redirect"]=='session') echo         "Your Session has Expired please login"; ?></span>
                    <form id="login" action="checklogin.php" method="POST" align="center">
                        <table border="0"  bgcolor="#FFFFCB" align="center"><br/>
                            <thead>please login below</thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>email:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username"  /></td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="warning" id="usernameinfo" name="usernameinfo">
                                        <?php
                                        if(isset($_GET["errno"]) && $_GET["errno"] == 1)
                                        echo "wrong username."
                                        ?>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>password:</td>
                                <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" /></td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="warning" id="passwordinfo" name="passwordinfo">
                                        <?php
                                        if(isset($_GET["errno"]) && $_GET["errno"] == 2)
                                        echo "wrong password.";
                                        ?>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <br />

                        <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="checklogin()"/>
                        <?php echo " New User?  <a href=\"register.php\"><b>Register freely!</b></a>"; ?>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi jon, I also have other pages that don't use innerhtml but the problem persists.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. It seems that you already know what's wrong: Firefox does not support `innerText`; that's because it's a *de facto* standard instead of a published one. Googling "Firefox innerText" will give you the exact same link mentioned above, you can find solutions there.

Comment: I have also removed the `ajax` tag from the question, since AJAX is unrelated to the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: No, sorry. If you need help with something specific then take some time to formulate and ask a proper question. If you don't know where to begin doing that then what you need is training, not answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use,

`document.getElementById('passwordinfo').textContent=''; //For firefox`

***or try***

```
document.getElementById('passwordinfo').innerHTML='';
```

For more info click [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Node.textContent)

Comment: hi can you also help me fix this pastebin.com/tSfQPQB8 – user3300861 6 mins ago

Comment: what is the problem you facing now?

Comment: the javascript responds only keyUp (thats what I know) I want to change it so that it also validates paste and select from autocomplete, thanks

Comment: use the help of jquery u can bind change function to a textbox...

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1):

innerText is not supported in firefox. Instead try innerHTML. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You also could use the html attribut `reguired` ([explain](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp)) wich is supported from the most major Browsers (only Safari not) to check the user input. 
For the email validation you could use the `type=email` propertie ([explain](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp)) to validate the email input which hase the same support as the required attribut.